# How to help SE content find its way into our documentation

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, retagging

How can we facilitate the flow of useful content from Stack Exchange into CiviCRM's documentation?

*This conversation began in [civicrm-docs#32](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-docs/issues/32).*

### Docs-worthy content

Examples:

- [disabling households](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/54/how-can-i-disable-households) could get referenced in [Organising your data > Contacts](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/contacts/)
- [preventing users from adding contacts to ACL groups](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-do-i-prevent-a-user-from-adding-contacts-to-acl-groups) could get added to [ACLs > Assign Users to Roles](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Assign+Users+to+Roles)
- [getting more than 25 results from the API](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/how-do-i-get-more-than-25-records-from-the-api) could get mentioned with a *"Note:"* in the [API Intro](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/api/general/)

I think in some cases a simple link to SE would be appropriate, and in others it might be better to copy-paste content.

### Non-docs-worthy content

By contrast, here's some content that, although *recent* and *popular*, doesn't belong in docs:

- [CiviCRM still creates MyISAM tables which results in Warning](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14444/civicrm-still-creates-myisam-tables-which-results-in-warning) - because it's moot now that a bug has been fixed
- [CiviCRM on Pantheon](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/what-is-required-to-run-civicrm-on-pantheon) - because it's too specific

Personally, I think the majority of SE content is not worth migrating to our documentation. But for content that *is*, what can we do to shepherd it over to our docs?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one idea that involves tracking content in SE with tags:

1. Begin using the following tags

   - [add-to-docs-to-do](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-to-docs-to-do) for content that should get captured in documentation
   - [add-to-docs-no](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-to-docs-no) for content that should not get captured
   - [add-to-docs-done](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-to-docs-done) for that has already been captured
2. To help **evaluate** what content to add or skip

   1. Search for the following *(79 results currently)*

      `is:question answers:1.. score:8.. -[add-to-docs-to-do] -[add-to-docs-no] -[add-to-docs-done]`
   2. Tag question with [add-to-docs-to-do](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-to-docs-to-do) or [add-to-docs-no](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-to-docs-no)
   3. Once we get this queue down to 0, documentarians like me could add an RSS feed to spot questions automatically.
3. To help **add** content to docs

   1. Search for:

      `[add-to-docs-to-do] -[add-to-docs-done]`
   2. Add content to docs. *(If it's already there, then consider trying to bring it to the surface a little more.)*
   3. Tag question with [add-to-docs-done](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-to-docs-done)

what does the SE community think of this idea? Would these tags present more clutter than they're worth?

Comment: The only thing I would add is that it would be good practice to link to the relevant section of the dev guide. I also wonder how to differentiate dev/user/admin guide content

Comment: It might be interesting to take a sample of those 79 results and have a range of people assess them for do/don't add to docs to see what level of agreement there is.

Comment: [From Chris](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/m96ybzth1fn5xjyqfkdmjcjdzw): I like it. I'd pick `cividocs-todo`, `cividocs-no` rather than `add-to-docs-no`, otherwise no complaints.

Comment: How do we limit usage of these tags? It's only helpful if not every random user is tagging their content as "add to docs".  Curious.